# Any of my php files on the server generated 500 "Internal Server Error"

Tags: php

Everything was working fine till last morning (12 hours  ago). But now each of PHP page is showing "500 Internal Server Error". Please look at this link http://abusadat.com. It's an WordPress site. I have thought it's about WordPress.

But I have a sub-domain, where there is a single PHP file - http://demo.abusadat.com/fb-apps/index.php, which gets same error. Though at the same location, there is a HTML file http://demo.abusadat.com/fb-apps/test.html, which works fine. To test if any syntax in PHP page causes that error, I have placed a "`die('some message')`" at the first line of that "`index.php`" file, but it shows same error. There is no HTAccess in that sub-domain.

Everything was working - suddenly all PHP stopped, I can't get the problem. Can anyone help?

**Edited:**
**Latest Error log from cPanel**

```
[Mon Jun 27 14:42:30 2011] [error] [client 59.93.241.43] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/404.shtml
[Mon Jun 27 14:42:30 2011] [error] [client 59.93.241.43] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/favicon.ico
[Mon Jun 27 14:42:29 2011] [error] [client 59.93.241.43] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/404.shtml
[Mon Jun 27 14:42:29 2011] [error] [client 59.93.241.43] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/favicon.ico
[Mon Jun 27 14:42:26 2011] [error] [client 59.93.241.43] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/404.shtml
[Mon Jun 27 14:42:26 2011] [error] [client 59.93.241.43] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/favicon.ico
[Mon Jun 27 14:40:53 2011] [error] [client 70.176.105.10] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/404.shtml
[Mon Jun 27 14:40:53 2011] [error] [client 70.176.105.10] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/favicon.ico
[Mon Jun 27 14:40:53 2011] [error] [client 70.176.105.10] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/404.shtml
[Mon Jun 27 14:40:53 2011] [error] [client 70.176.105.10] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/favicon.ico
[Mon Jun 27 14:40:53 2011] [error] [client 70.176.105.10] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/500.shtml, referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497358/any-of-my-php-files-on-the-server-generated-500-internal-server-error
[Mon Jun 27 14:40:00 2011] [error] [client 180.234.41.26] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/500.shtml
[Mon Jun 27 14:39:48 2011] [error] [client 180.234.41.26] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/404.shtml
[Mon Jun 27 14:39:48 2011] [error] [client 180.234.41.26] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/fb-app
[Mon Jun 27 14:39:34 2011] [error] [client 109.132.111.25] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/404.shtml
[Mon Jun 27 14:39:34 2011] [error] [client 109.132.111.25] File does not exist: /home/abusadat/public_html/demo.abusadat/favicon.ico
```

Thanks,
Sadat

Comment: We need log files to know what is going on. Your log files will show you why you are getting an 500 error.

Comment: What errors are showing in your server logs?

Comment: what do your logs say on the server?

Comment: please add some output from our error log here. Only the 500 page is just not enough.

Comment: did you make any update of your website ? can you try a static page ? can you trust your webhost (i mean, aren't they on maintenance) ?

Comment: i have added last error logs with the question

Comment: @Thomas, I have tried a static page and mentioned the question too- http://demo.abusadat.com/fb-apps/test.html

Comment: @Sadat: The Apache log does not appear to contain your PHP errors. Can you post your PHP error log?

Comment: @George, when a php error occured, a error_log file is created(if not exists) in that folder and appended new error message to that file. But no error_log file is craeted for this internal server error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your log files to determine if an automatic update occurred around the time the problem first appeared. Also check if Apache (or your web server) was restarted around that time, activating a previous update.

Comment: this is a shared hosting. How can i know and trace about any system/webserver/php update?

Comment: @Sadat: You should contact the technical support department of your hosting company. They will have a record of any server maintenance. Also, you should check with everyone that has administrative rights to your hosting account to see if they installed new software or changed any configurations.

Comment: thanks @George. I will contact with hosting company. I am the only one who administer my domains and hosting.